# Front - back authorities interation

Tags: authentication, frontend, backend

The question is, where I should make decision to hide/show actions for different roles.

For example, I have to roles: master and apprentice. Master and apprentice can do some work, but master also can approve apprentice actions. So I have similar interfaces for master and apprentice, with difference in one button "master approve". Where should I make decision to draw this button?

1. My frontend know the user role and choose if this action is available?
2. Using HATEOAS or smth like that, with some request backend send available actions, and frontend draw only recived actions?

I like (2), but never seen such practice, only some theoretical sources.

Comment: You should never leave authorization issues to the client.

Comment: I see, but I'd like to find different ways to do this.

Comment: The easiest way is to just "filter" the response based on the authorization profile of the user. By filter I here mean "don't generate" the parts the authenticated user doesn't have authorization for. (You'll need to set your Vary headers so you don't serve cached content with high authorization).

Comment: ok, I see. For example (cause of spring) I can take https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS. So send only links to available actions

Comment: That looks like a typical Java overdesigned interface/protocol, but yes.

Comment: @thebjorn need one more advice. I have two entities (for example balls and cubes), but *cubes* is forbidden for users without `ROLE_ADMIN`. As I understand, my root endpoint `/` should return links `{"balls": {...}}` for common users and `{"balls": {...}, "cubes": {...}}` for admins?

Comment: That sounds like a new question (ie. ask it as a new question).

Comment: And building front I firstly need to ask `/` and if I found both entities in answer, I should display both buttons to surf collections. So keep display logic on user roles only in my backend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168487/front-back-responsibilities-to-display-browsable-items